# Put both a bullet and a label

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to place both a bullet and a label ?

```
    \documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, quotes, shapes.geometric}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,>=Stealth,x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={thick}]
       \node (a) at (0,4) {A};
       \node (b) at (5,4) {B};
       \node (c) at (5,0) {C};
       \node (d) at (0,0) {D};
       \node (e) at (7.5,2){E};
     \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[ every edge/.style={draw=blue,very thick}]
       \path [->] (a) edge[bend left=30] (b);
       \path [->] (b) edge[bend left=30] (a);
       \path [->] (d) edge[bend left=0] (a);
       \path [->] (d) edge[bend left=0] (c);
       \path [->] (a) edge[bend left=0] (c);
       \path [->] (b) edge[bend left=0] (c);
       \path [->] (c) edge[bend left=0] (e);
       \path [->] (b) edge[bend left=0] (e);
    \end{scope}

   \foreach \x in {(a), (b), (c), (d), (e)}{
    \fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
    }

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for `label`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very
thick,>={Stealth[bend]},x=1cm,y=1cm,bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=2pt}]
\begin{scope}[nodes=bullet]
   \node[label=above:A] (a) at (0,4) {};
   \node[label=above:B] (b) at (5,4) {};
   \node[label=below:C] (c) at (5,0) {};
   \node[label=below:D] (d) at (0,0) {};
   \node[label=right:E] (e) at (7.5,2){};
 \end{scope}
\begin{scope}[ every edge/.style={draw=blue,very thick}]
   \path [->] (a) edge[bend left=30] (b)
    (b) edge[bend left=30] (a)
    (d) edge[bend left=0] (a)
    (d) edge[bend left=0] (c)
    (a) edge[bend left=0] (c)
    (b) edge[bend left=0] (c)
    (c) edge[bend left=0] (e)
    (b) edge[bend left=0] (e);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you master a lot and I am still learning.